# "clicking" animation of imageButton

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imagebutton

im trying to send data to a server when an Imagebutton is touched or not. I Implemented those things the problem is that after I used onTouch events and etc, the animation of the touch disappered.

1 of the buttonImages xml :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/lt_onclick" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/lt_onclick" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/lt_noclick" />
```

i figure out that because i used onTouch i might need to activate an animtaion when ACTION_DOWN or ACTION_UP  but i dont know how do it.

onTouch method:

```
private void onControl(String st, MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        Log.d("onControl","inside"+" "+st);
        new SendMessage().execute("S"+st);
    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        Log.d("onControl","inside"+" "+st);
        new SendMessage().execute("P"+st);
    }
}

private View.OnTouchListener handleTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.Abtn:
            onControl("BA",event);
            break;
        case R.id.Bbtn:
            onControl("BB", event);
            break;
        case R.id.Xbtn:
            onControl("BX",event);
            break;
        case R.id.Ybtn:
            onControl("BY",event);
            break;
        case R.id.Rbtn:
            onControl("BR",event);
            break;
        case R.id.Lbtn:
            onControl("BL",event);
            break;
        case R.id.UpBtn:
            onControl("BU",event);
            break;
        case R.id.Dbtn:
            onControl("BD",event);
            break;
        case R.id.RTbtn:
            onControl("RT",event);
            break;
        case R.id.LTbtn:
            onControl("LT",event);
            break;
        case R.id.Start_btn:
            onControl("ST", event);
            break;
        case R.id.Back_btn:
            onControl("CK",event);
            break;
        case R.id.RB_btn:
            onControl("RB",event);
            break;
        case R.id.LB_btn:
            onControl("LB",event);
            break;


    }
    return true;
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this problem in other way.
I called MainActivity.super.onTouchEvent(event);
instead of return true and it made even better animation.